# My ASP .NET MVC 3 project starts in Windows Phone 7 emulator?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Here's a screenshot of how it looks before I press the green "debug" button.

[image]

However, the project still attempts to start using the Windows Phone Emulator. It's really bad.

Is this a problem you've encountered before? How can I solve it?

**Edit 1** In my project file, I see something strange:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Is it supposed to be like that for that given project?

**Edit 2** It should probably be noted that one of the projects in the solution is in fact a Windows Phone 7 application.

Comment: Try right clicking your MVC3 **project** and open a new debug instance from there. What happens?

Comment: That works as expected, but with no debugging. Breakpoints don't work at all, and there's no debug information attached.

Comment: Wow, I knew I should never install the WP SDK :-)

Comment: Ok, now try this. Select another project in your solution as the default starting project. Then **reselect** your MVC3 project. Press F5 and see if it's now fixed.

Comment: I noticed something weird in the project maybe. I added an edit to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a workaround. Unloading the Windows Phone 7 project from the solution temporarily as I work on the ASP .NET MVC site seems to work just fine.